# SELECT COUNT(SomeId) with INSERT later to same SomeId: Appropriate locking strategy?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, locking, deadlock

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have a repeatable read transaction where I perform this query:

```
select count(SomeId)
from dbo.MyTable
where SomeId = @SomeId
```

`SomeId` is a column whose value may repeat in the table (think foreign key). However, `SomeId` is not a member of any index nor is it a foreign key.

Later in the transaction, I insert a record into `dbo.MyTable` with the same `@SomeId`, thus changing what the `select count(*)` would return were I to run it again:

```
insert into dbo.MyTable (SomeId, ...)
values (@SomeId, ...)
```

Several threads in my application can execute this transaction at the same time. Because of this, I'm getting deadlocks on the `insert` statement. At first, I thought an `updlock` would be appropriate on the `select` statement, but I quickly realized that it wouldn't work because I'm not actually updating the rows selected by the `select count(SomeId)`.

My question is this: is there any way to avoid a potentially expensive table lock? Is there any way to lock just rows that involve `SomeId`, even if they haven't been inserted yet (strange, I know)? I want to force other threads to wait while the original transaction completes its work but I don't want to lock rows unnecessarily.

**EDIT**

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I only want to insert up to eight rows for a particular `SomeId`. There are several unrelated processes that can start one of these transactions, potentially at the same time. The `select count` detects whether there are already eight rows and causes the operation to fail for that process. If the count is less than eight, that same transaction performs additional work, then inserts a record at the end, thus effectively incrementing the count were the `select count` to be run again. I am hitting the deadlock on the `insert` statement.

Comment: Your description makes me suspect that you might be approaching this the wrong way. Could you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sure, I'll add some more context.

Comment: I am thinking that perhaps creating an index on `SomeId` would be a good choice, and then somehow locking the index for a particular `SomeId`. I'm not that familiar with locking on this level, so I'm just intuiting. :)

Comment: I tried a tablock on `select count` and it still deadlocked. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several processes that try to do the same thing and you don't want to have more records than some number, you will need to actually prevent those processes from running at the the same time.

One way would be to read the counts with exclusive lock:

```
select count(SomeId)
from dbo.MyTable with (xlock)
where SomeId = @SomeId
```

This way those records will be blocked until the transaction completes.

You should create an index for the `SomeId` column though as it will be most likely that the locks will be on held on the index level this way.

Comment: I will try this. I've been reading up on locking right now and it seems to be a common recommendation to create an index for the `where`d column.

Comment: Yes, the index will help. Not only for locking but also for selecting.

Comment: My dev database doesn't have any indexes (other than PKs) but I do add them in production. This will have to be an exception since it helps enforce correct application behavior.

Comment: I think it's better to have the same indexes in dev as in production. Helps to develop in exactly the same environment.

Comment: Unfortunately I got some of my initial research wrong. I am going to forget this question and open a new one, this time with much more detailed (and accurate) information. Thanks for your contribution, though; you got me looking in the right place!